# How to query and sort by filtered Max query in EF4?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Context: EF4, C#, .NET4, SQL2008/R2

Tables/entities to repro problem:

- `Account (long Id, string Name, etc.)`
- `Order (long Id, DateTime
  DateToExecute, int OrderStatus, etc.)`
- `AccountOrder (long Id, long
  AccountId, long OrderId)` <- Yes, one account may have many orders and, likewise, one order may be associated with many accounts.
- `OrderedItem (long Id, long OrderId, long
  ItemId, etc)` <- One order may have many items, and we want to eager-load these items (I realize this has performance/data size implications).

Pseudocode (nearly real code) that would be ideal to work:

```
DateTime startDateInclusive = xxxx;
DateTime stopDateExclusive = yyy;

var query = Db.Accounts.Include(a => a.AccountOrders.Select(ao => ao.Order.Ordereditems.Select(oi => oi.Item)))
              .Where(account =>
                     account.AccountOrders.Where(ao => ao.OrderStatus != 42)
                            .Max(ao => ao.DateToExecute).IsBetween(startDateInclusive, stopDateExclusive))
              .OrderBy(account =>
                       account.AccountOrders.Where(ao => ao.OrderStatus != 42)
                              .Max(ao => ao.DateToExecute));

var results = query.Take(5).ToList();
```

In English, this is looking for the next 5 accounts that have their last order to be executed within a date range. However, there are also Orders that can be cancelled, so we must exclude OrderStatus of 42 when performing that Max.

The problem revolves around this filtered Max date across many-to-many tables. An added complexity is that we need to sort by that filtered max value and we must do all of the above without breaking our eager loading (i.e. joins must be done via projection in the Where and not using a .Join). I’m not sure how to do this query without the result being 10x’s more complex than it should be. I’d hate to do the joins to filter the ao.OrderStatus/Max the DateToExecute 3 times (once for startDate, once for stopDate, and once for the sort). And clearly the IsBetween isn’t functional.

**Any ideas on how to perform this query, sorted this way, in a fairly-efficient way for the generated SQL?**

Comment: FYI, while this strongly-typed `.Include` isn't standard, if functions the same as if it were `.Include("AccountOrders.Order.OrderedItems.Item")`, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to use an anonymous type here:

```
DateTime startDateInclusive = xxxx;
DateTime stopDateExclusive = yyy;

var query = Db.Accounts
              .Select(account => new { 
                  Account = account,
                  MaxDate = account.AccountOrders.Select(ao => ao.Order).Where(o => o.OrderStatus != 42).Max(o => o.DateToExecute) 
              })
              .Where(a => a.MaxDate >= startDateInclusive && a.MaxDate < stopDateExclusive)
              .OrderBy(a => a.MaxDate)
              .Select(a => a.Account)
              .Include(a => a.AccountOrders.Select(ao => ao.Order.Ordereditems.Select(oi => oi.Item)));

var results = query.Take(5).ToList();
```

This is untested as I don't have any datasource to test against.  But it's probably the simplest approach for what you need to do.

Comment: That won't work. This will break the eager-loading because you change the `Select` portion of the generated SQL. Once you say `.Include`, you can't have anything else that will affect the `SELECT` or `FROM` portions of the generated SQL statement. Not my rule - talk to Microsoft. :-(  Now that said, might be able to adjust how you've written the query to both use an anonymous and not break the `.Include`. However, I'm unsure how.

Comment: Ok, can we move the .Include to the bottom of the query?  See updated

Comment: Hmm, actually, I don't know. Let me see if something like that works. I'll respond tomorrow on this. Thanks for that idea!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but that ended up being problematic as well. I ultimately went with a derivation of your solution and performed some explicit lazy-loading after-the-fact to include add'l properties. Not what I wanted but I had to get something working. And since I'm at-most only loading up 5 records, that's not too terrible of a solution.